# removing index.php in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I used the code below to remove index.php in codeigniter in my .htaccess file. But the thing that I am confused is where should i use the file. should i use it inside my www folder outside the application or inside the application.

I used it in all places, and it worked but it is messing up with my css or say base folders. How can I overcome the problem. Should i use the html base tag?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

**EDIT**

my folder structure is

```
basefolder
  -application
  -css
  -js
  -images   
  -system
.htaccess
index.php
```

Comment: it goes in the CI installation directory. In your case it may be www. You can exclude media folders in the rewrite rules

Comment: can u give me the idea how to exclude them?

Comment: http://www.farinspace.com/codeigniter-htaccess-file/ here is a codeigniter .htaccess you can use . .

Comment: i updated. simply add the directories delimited by a pipe to the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

if doesn't works check if you `enabled mod_rewirte` in `phpinfo();`

if it doesn't works yet, try to change the `$config['uri_protocol']='AUTO'` to one of the listed inside `application/config/config.php` file on line 40/54:

```
|
| 'AUTO'            Default - auto detects
| 'PATH_INFO'       Uses the PATH_INFO
| 'QUERY_STRING'    Uses the QUERY_STRING
| 'REQUEST_URI'     Uses the REQUEST_URI
| 'ORIG_PATH_INFO'  Uses the ORIG_PATH_INFO
|
*/
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

sometimes i used : `REQUEST_URI` instead of `AUTO`

Answer (score 2):

You can add an RewriteCondition which excludes all exisiting files:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|js|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

This assumes css is in the same directory as index.php, etc. This rule depends on your file structure. If you update your question with an example of your directory tree I can modify the rules.

There should be no other configuration needed for this since you mention it works but just messes things up.

It should be noted, this one pasted is the only thing in my CI htaccess file and mine works fine.

Also, see Will's comment. My config url suffix is always ""

Comment: as far as codeigniter goes however, you also have to update the config file and set $config['url_suffix'] to ""

Answer (score 0):

My solution, CI system move up (not public from the web), applications are public, `.htaccess` for each subdomains (in root directory), but its depends on your structure (many solutions exists)

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

copy and paste below code in .htaccess file

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://www.yoursite.com/ [R=301,L]